# URL encoding with php and javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, url, symfony1

I am working on existing project. At some points it has some poor implementation.

For example I found following code in an action:

```
<?php
    echo "<script>window.location='/".$this->getRequestParameter("culture")."/profile/".$this->username';</script>"; 
?>
```

In normal condition above code works fine and redirect user successfully. But problems occurs when username is something like this:

```
Uneståhl
```

It converts it into

```
UnestÃ¥l
```

And a server error is returned.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: When it is redirected,I saw converted code in browser address bar..

Comment: I just tried such thing (with `window.location='Uneståhl`) and the browser didn't change the value. Tried with IE9 and Chrome. What browser you tried?

Comment: Independently from your problem: this looks like an attempt to simulate a redirect with JavaScript. You should be using a proper redirect - especially since you are using PHP anyway.

Comment: So it's likely PHP issue, converting it somewhere.

Comment: This looks like a character set mismatch problem. The "converted" version looks like UTF-8 expressed in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using PHP `urlencode` function:

```
<?php
    echo "<script>window.location='/".$this->getRequestParameter("culture")."/profile/".urlencode($this->username). "';</script>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Fixed but It is working with `urlencode()`. `url_encode()` is giving me function not found error.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the mistake. I will update the answer.